# shell script to iterate through text files and delete a string

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, sed

I have a few hundred text files in one directory with lists of users:

```
&usera
&userb
userc
&userd
```

note that some do not lead with the `&`. Also, in some files, the last line does not end with a newline character.

What is the simplest way in a shell script to go through all those files and remove, say `userb`, ensuring that each existing user remains on its own line?

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find /directory -name '*.users' -exec sed -i -r '/^&?userb$/d' {} \;
```

Comment: thanks! though I had to quote: `'{}'` the filename reference

Comment: You should probably change the sed command to `'/^&?userb$/d'` to avoid deleting, say, "otheruserbeth" by mistake.